# FreeBSD kldload: can't load, No such file or directory

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, freebsd, system-calls

I am new to kernel and KLD programming. I am looking to modify the example file in FreeBSD for system call module. My question is, is it possible to fork or exec inside system call function? Like in the following example?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>    

/*
 * The function for implementing the syscall.
 */
static int hello (struct thread *td, void *arg)
{
    printf("Running...\n");
    /******************************************************/
    /*Something like this?*/
    /******************************************************/
    execl("/bin/pwd", "pwd", NULL);
    return 0;
}

/*
 * The `sysent' for the new syscall
 */

static struct sysent hello_sysent = {
    0,          /* sy_narg */
    hello           /* sy_call */
};

/*
 * The offset in sysent where the syscall is allocated.
 */

static int offset = NO_SYSCALL;

/*
 * The function called at load/unload.
 */

static int
load (struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg)
{
    int error = 0;

    switch (cmd) {
    case MOD_LOAD :
        uprintf ("syscall loaded at %d\n", offset);
        break;
    case MOD_UNLOAD :
        uprintf ("syscall unloaded from %d\n", offset);
        break;
    default :
        uprintf("There was some error!");
        error = EINVAL;
        break;
    }
    return error;
}

SYSCALL_MODULE(syscall, &offset, &hello_sysent, load, NULL);
```

There is no compilation error (syscall), but while loading it using kldload, it returns an error:
kldload: can't load ./syscall.ko: No such file or directory

Is there something I can read and know more about why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried giving it a full path?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I can see the syscall.ko file is there.

Comment: Check dmesg output, using kldload -v ./syscall.ko, and file syscall.ko. Make sure that you are pulling against the source tree of the running kernel and the right arch (i386 vs amd64 for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When kldload returns "No such file or directory", or some other weird error, first do "dmesg" and look for any errors at the bottom.  In this case it's probably due to a missing symbol "execl".  That's because execl is a userspace API (man 3 execl), and you're trying to use it in kernel.

What you're trying to do doesn't seem to be a good idea, but it's possible.  Look at sys/kern/kern_exec.c:kern_execve().

Comment: Thank you. This is response I was looking for.